# Increase Graphstream Edge width

Tags: java, graphstream

Is there any way to increase a Graphstream's Edge width?

What I've tried:

```
edge.addAttribute("ui.style", "stroke-width: 30px; fill-color: red;");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the `size` property.

```
edge.addAttribute("ui.style", "size: 5px; fill-color: red;");
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```java
graph.setAttribute("ui.stylesheet", "edge{size:30px;}");
```